# AssertionError: External ID must be fully qualified in odoo

Tags: xml, python-2.7, openerp-7, openerp-8

I am working on Odoo CRM. I inherited CRM.lead I added some functionality I added new user roles to them.

Admin thing is working fine when I given user roles which I created now it's throwing error.

File ".........base/res/res_users.py", in has_group assert group_ext_id and '.' in group_ext_id, "External ID must be fully qualified"

"AssertionError: External ID must be fully qualified"

I tried but can't.

Help me if you know your valuable suggestion very help full for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `has_group` method of `res.users` is not getting the fully qualified group id. I don't know what happened there but you can bypass that error by overriding the `has_group` method.

For that first create a new model that inherit the `res.users` in your custom module. The code would be like:

```
class Users(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.users'
    _columns = {}

    def has_group(self,cr,uid,group_ext_id):
         if '.' in group_ext_id:
              users_group1 = [x.id for x in self.pool['ir.model.data'].get_object(cr, uid, 'bms',  'xml_id_group1').users]
              users_group2 = [x.id for x in self.pool['ir.model.data'].get_object(cr, uid, 'bms',  'xml_id_group2').users]

              if uid in users_group1:
                  return super(Users,self).has_group(cr,uid,'module.xml_id_group1')
              elif uid in users_group2:
                  return super(Users,self).has_group(cr,uid,'module.xml_id_group2')
              else:
                  return super(Users,self).has_group(cr,uid,'base.group_user')

         else:
             return super(Users,self).has_group(cr,uid,group_ext_id)
```

In place of `xml_id_group1` and `xml_id_group2` place your group IDs for the groups you are getting the above error with.

I hope this will help!